# Using ffmpeg with subprocess python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, subprocess, wistia

I am trying to download videos from Wistia and I managed to download them but in .bin&amp format ; I'd like to convert them to .mp4 in order to use OpenCV. For this I am calling ffmpeg with subprocess on Python but I get 1 as the value for the return code, meaning the process has failed. Any idea why, and how I can change this...?

Code is the following:

```
import subprocess

infile = filename #a bin&amp file
outfile = filename[:-7]+'mp4'

subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', infile, outfile],shell=True)
```

I get :

```
CompletedProcess(args=['ffmpeg', '-i', '58c63bccfcc1c150646c261caad97a58ced4b5e3.bin&amp', '58c63bccfcc1c150646c261caad97a58ced4b5e3.mp4'], returncode=1)
```

Also, it works in the command prompt...

Thank you for your help,

Sincerely,

Comment: Try removing `shell=True`.

Comment: Thank you for your help but it doesn't seem to work... Only I can see a command window quickly opening and closing...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Popen. I I'm using FFmpeg in python and it works well

```
process_ = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, start_new_session=True)
```